# what will happen if intercepted method called another intercepted method

Tags: byte-buddy

using bytebuddy to intercept class Foo, whihc has two method A,B

in A method, B method get called. if we deleget both A and B to C method in intercetpor class Bar, which call `callable#call` at first line

what will happen ? what's the execution sequence of those methods ?

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.wxt.xtools.agents;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.isAbstract;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.namedOneOf;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.not;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.JavaModule;

class Foo {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("method A");
        methodB();
    }
    
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("method B");
    }
}

class Bar {
    @RuntimeType
    public static void interceptor(@Origin Class<?> clazz, @Origin Method method, @SuperCall Callable<?> callable,
            @net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.This Object inst) throws Exception {
        callable.call();
        System.out.println("intercepting " + method.getName());
    }
}

public class Test {
    
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws IOException {
        AgentBuilder.Transformer methodsTransformer = new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
            @Override
            public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                    ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
                return builder.method(namedOneOf("methodA", "methodB").and(not(isAbstract())))
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Bar.class));
            }
        };

        AgentBuilder.Listener listener = new AgentBuilder.Listener.WithErrorsOnly(
                new AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting(System.out));

        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(named("org.wxt.xtools.agents.Foo")).transform(methodsTransformer)
                .with(listener).installOn(inst);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        premain(null, ByteBuddyAgent.install());
        new Foo().methodA();
    }

}
```

results

```
method A
method B
intercepting methodB
intercepting methodA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course just try it, but what will happen is that the internal call will again be intercepted. Methods do not know who is calling them. To avoid this, you can discover the caller via a `StackWalker` or by generating a stack trace using an exception.